# How to scroll Data using Scroll API elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

**i am new to elk stack**

- i have tried from [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/scroll-api.html) but not getting working flow ..
- for example executed below search query

```
POST <index-name>/_search?scroll=2m
{
  "query": {"match_all": {}}
}
```

- and got the scroll_id from this query then tried Retrieving the next batch of results for a scrolling search.using this

```
GET /_search/scroll
{
  "scroll_id" : "<scroll_id>"
}
```

- got result first time

```
"took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "terminated_early" : true,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 13059,
      "relation" : "eq"
    }
```

- my question is why i am getting error when i tried scrolling again using same scroll_id

```
"caused_by" : {
      "type" : "search_context_missing_exception",
      "reason" : "No search context found for id"
```

- Versions Used

```
Kibana 7.9.3
Elastic Search 7.9.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `scroll_id` value changes in every response. So the next search call needs to use the new scroll id from the previous search response.

You started correctly with

```
POST <index-name>/_search?scroll=2m
{
  "query": {"match_all": {}}
}
```

In the response you get, a field called `_scroll_id` contains the next scroll id to use for the next call (like a cursor), let's call it `scroll_id_1`:

```
GET /_search/scroll
{
  "scroll_id" : "<scroll_id_1>",
  "scroll": "2m"
}
```

In that next response, you get a new `_scroll_id` value (let's call it `scroll_id_2`) that you need to use it for the next call:

```
GET /_search/scroll
{
  "scroll_id" : "<scroll_id_2>",
  "scroll": "2m"
}
```

And you keep doing it until you get an empty result set, at which point you can clear the search context

```
DELETE /_search/scroll
{
  "scroll_id" : "<scroll_id_n>"
}
```

Comment: but i didn't got the `scroll_id_2` when i executed this `GET /_search/scroll
{
  "scroll_id" : "<scroll_id_1>"
}`, error attached in question

Comment: The field in the response body is called `_scroll_id`

Comment: sorry , but didnt getting what you trying to convey

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: 7.9.3 for both kibana nd elasticsearch

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong somewhere along the path. I have the same version and it works exactly that way. Please re-read carefully my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224181/discussion-between-m-x-and-val).

Comment: Make sure to specify the scroll time in each request.

Comment: Thank you @Val for the wonderful answer on scroll_api. i was searching a workable query using scroll_api and found this. Thank you